# Installing symfony2 cmf composer issues

Tags: symfony, composer-php, symfony-cmf

Pretty new to Symfony, I want to get the CMF to work but I'm having issues installing it using composer

When running the code in terminal I get this

> Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.
>   Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - Installation request for symfony/icu 1.2.x-dev -> satisfiable by symfony/icu[1.2.x-dev].
>       - symfony/icu 1.2.x-dev requires lib-icu >=4.4 -> the requested linked library icu has the wrong version installed or is missing from
>   your system, make sure to have the extension providing it.
>
> Problem 2
>        - symfony/icu 1.2.x-dev requires lib-icu >=4.4 -> the requested linked library icu has the wrong version installed or is missing from
>    your system, make sure to have the extension providing it.
>        - symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev requires symfony/icu ~1.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/icu[1.2.x-dev].
>        - Installation request for symfony/symfony 2.3.x-dev -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[2.3.x-dev].

As requested my composer.json looks like this...

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
        "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
        "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "2.3.*@dev"    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.3-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

I have run

```
composer.phar update
```

And get no errors but the other problems are a bit of a mystery to me

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: Can you show us the content of your `composer.json` ?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this comment: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1939#issuecomment-18510052 . You have to install php5-intl.